# Android - NullPointerException with canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas

i'm creating an android game to introduce myself to this technology, so i have a class GameView that is extended from a View, everything is working fine, but after the game run for some time(short but undefined) the game crashes, looking at the android log the error come from: "android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawBitmap(GLES20Canvas.java:779)", but if we go back into the source(it should be written  by me) we have the GameView.OnDraw, but, this canvas object is passed for this overloaded function, so why is it null???? i'll show you my code:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();//As sugested on web

    super.onDraw(canvas);//As sugested on web

    //draw the current phase of the game
    c_phase.draw(canvas);

    //the shot delay
    if(shot_delay.counting){
        canvas.drawText("Delay: " + String.valueOf(shot_delay.getRest()), 10, canvas.getHeight()-10, color);
    }

    canvas.restore();//as sugested on web
}
```

if you think that the c_phase.draw is necessary:

```
    @Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas){

            //draw de background
    canvas.drawBitmap(map, new Rect(0, 0, map.getWidth(), map.getHeight()), new Rect(0, 0, map.getWidth()+view.getWidth(), map.getHeight()+view.getHeight()), null);
}
```

for while is just this, so, why i got this error? i did not create the object and i'm not supposed to destroy it, i just need to use it and that's all! if someone could help i'll thank you :s

_**EDITED**
here is the log error:

04-10 10:32:48.507: E/AndroidRuntime(2890): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 10:32:48.507: E/AndroidRuntime(2890): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-10 10:32:48.507: E/AndroidRuntime(2890):     at my.test.shooter.TestPhase.draw(DuckPhase.java:56)
04-10 10:32:48.507: E/AndroidRuntime(2890):     at my.test.shooter.GameView.onDraw(GameView.java:97)
04-10 10:32:48.507: E/AndroidRuntime(2890):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13826)
04-10 10:32:48.507: E/AndroidRuntime(2890):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12777)
04-10 10:32:48.507: E/AndroidRuntime(2890):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12821)
04-10 10:32:48.507: E/AndroidRuntime(2890):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2970)

Comment: Please post the error logs.

Comment: Are you sure `map` and `view` are not null?

Comment: yes, the game run for a undetermined time, and when it is running he can draw the map and the view can respond to the events like when i touch the screen, but then he just crash, i'm playing he for 10 minutes i guess and he haven't crashed yet, i don't know what is this